# Eight numbers in a cross- Wrong Output has zero's

Tags: c++, arrays, goto

Ok, so for my assignment I need 1-8 numbers in a cross. In the array the adjacent boxes can't be consecutive. The output should be
Solution #1

```
 53
2817
 64
```

Solution #2

```
 64
2817
 53
```

Solution #3

```
 35
7182
 46
```

Solution #4

```
 46
7182
 35
```

However in my program I have zeros and I can't seem to figure out where in my algorithm is causing the 0's. I tried to figure it out by debugging the program, however I still need more practice debugging a program. Can someone give me pointers on where to find the problem within my code. My code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
bool okay(int q[], int col) {
static int a[8][5] = { // Helper Array
 {-1},
 {0, -1},
 {0, 1, -1},
 {0, 2, -1},
 {1, 2, -1},
 {1, 2, 3, 4, -1},
 {2, 3, 5, -1},
 {4, 5, 6, -1}
};
for (int i = 0; i < col; i++){ //row check
    if (q[i] == q[col])
    return false;
}


for (int i = 0; a[col][i] != -1; i++){ //check if numbers are consecutive
    if (abs(q[col] - q[a[col][i]]) == 1)
     return false;
}
 return true;
}



void backtrack(int& c){ //
--c;
if (c < 0)
exit (1);
}

void print(int q[]){
static int solutions = 0;
cout << "Solution#" << ++solutions << "\n";
cout << " "  << q[1] << q[4] << "\n";
cout << q[0] << q[2] << q[5] << q[7] << "\n";
cout << " "  << q[3] << q[6] << "\n\n";
}

int main(){
int q[8];
int c = 0;
q[c] = 1; //place

while (true){ //backtrack will end loop once solution is found
    while (c >= 0){ //
        ++c;
        if (c == 8){ // if all solutions were found print
            print(q);
            backtrack(c);
        } 
        else {
            q[c] = 0;
        }
        while ( c >= 0){
            ++q[c];
            if (q[c] > 8){ //if no solutions were found in a row
                backtrack(c);
                continue;
            }
            else {
                if (okay(q, c)) { //if number is ok break and go to next col
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Bug:  `q[8] = 0;`. `q[8]` is out of bounds. The `goto`s in the code will give you plenty of practice debugging, trust me. Save yourself a load of work, get rid of the `goto`s and replace them with functions and loops. Then give your variables descriptive names so your code is conducive to reading.

Comment: *I can't seem to figure out where in my algorithm* -- There is no algorithm.  You are using `goto` all over the place, thus creating [spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code)

Comment: @user4581301  Yeah, my professor has us using goto statements in class at the moment. I'll change it up using functions and loops and update you guys on my progress.

Comment: Wow. I don't think I've ever seen anyone actually teach `goto`. The point of the lesson may come down to, "Absolute <expletive deleted> to debug eh? Now you know not to use `goto` without good reason." `goto` has little gotchas with respect to variable scope and `try`/`catch` blocks, so use with caution.

Comment: @asherchapman I know of no teacher that encourages `goto` in a high-level language.  If anything, points on exams, assignments, etc. are deducted if `goto` is used, and you're lucky if it's just points and not an outright failure.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I think he's probably just giving us an introduction to the topic. Also, I figured it out using functions and gotos. So it was definitely a huge help.